# How to install alien on KUBUNTU

Tags: kubuntu

How to install alien on kubuntu?

Comment: maybe `sudo apt install alien`?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Alien allows you to convert and install rpm and other packages which can be installed with `dpkg`.

Comment: ... except that it usually produces unsolvable dependencies in the package due to differences in naming of libraries in Debiam and RedHat worlds.